# Angular style not apply in forms

Tags: css, angular, forms

I am new for angular .I wrote below code and I expect below style format with my code but i can't achieve using my below code can some one help me to solve my issue.

### home.component.html

```
<div class="card">
  <form [formGroup]="userForm">
    <div class="mt-5 box">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group mt-4">
            <label>Type</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row" style="margin-top:-10px">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" formControlName="type" class="form-control" placeholder="Type">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group mt-4">
            <label>Session</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row" style="margin-top:-10px">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" formControlName="session" class="form-control" placeholder="Session">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row mt-4">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addItem()">Add</button>&nbsp
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="col-md-8 mt-4 mb-4">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of listData">
          <td><span>{{item.type}}</span></td>
          <td><span>{{item.session}}</span></td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="removeItems(item)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

### home.component.css

```
.box{
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid rgb(145, 138, 138);
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
margin-left: 400px;
}
```

### My Result

[image]

### Expected

[image]

### angular.json

[image]

Comment: Are you using angular material? If yes, then have you added their style in global css?

Comment: i am not using material

Comment: Bootstrap perhaps? You will have to add both of these dependencies for css to work - based on the classes you have used in html

Comment: The question is where are you applying the css in global or in the component?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara i am using in the component

Comment: @DrashtiDobariya i updated my classes please check once

Comment: Can some one help on it?

Comment: Have you tried to put `.card  .box` in the component.css? If it dont work put it in the global for testing else your shadow dom might be enabled.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: I already test to put itin the global css file

Comment: @Krish Shouldn't the `div` with CSS class `.box` encapsulate the `form`? That is, `<div class="mt-5 box">` should open before `<form [formGroup]="userForm">` and close after the `</form>`.

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh i tried but not working

Comment: Could you please add the declaration for the `styles` property from the `angular.json` file to your question, if possible?

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh i added please check once

Comment: Thanks, could you please move `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` to the top of the `styles` property. Such that, `src/styles.css` is appearing after it.

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh i tried but no luck still not showing expected result